# CN1 native Google+ login not working on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm trying to implement social media login in a CodenameOne app using Google+ as explained [here](http://www.codenameone.com/google-login.html) but I can't get it to work.

Sometimes, I get a dialog with all the active google accounts on the device (there are multiple of them) after which I get a null pointer exception. From the adb logs, the NPE occurs because the `getAccessToken()` method of the GoogleConnect instance is null when I try accessing it in the `loginSuccessful()` callback.

Other times, the app simply freezes after calling `GoogleConnect.doLogin()` and there's nothing in the logs suggesting what is going wrong. Everything works fine in the simulator and on iOS.

Has anyone experienced similar issues and does anyone know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the back and forth issues with the gradle support. We [deployed a new version yesterday](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/seo-gallery-performance-javascript-gradle.html) which should restore gradle functionality and hopefully fix this issue.

Comment: Ok. I'll check again and let you know. BTW, it would be great if the [Login API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/social/Login.html) includes an option to revert to web-based oAuth even on platforms where the native flow is supported. That would be a workaround for such issues and allow development to continue (I missed a non-critical deadline because of this Google+ problem and could have avoided that with such an API)

Comment: We have the versioned build support. By targeting 3.3 which is relatively recent you could use a stabler target when building.

Comment: That would solve the immediate problem but there could be other reasons why someone won't want to use the native flow in which case this API change would still be useful :)

Comment: Can you give an example of this? You could always use the OAuth2 code directly to get the web login working. This is pretty trivial as you can see in the actual fallback implementation: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/social/GoogleConnect.java

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me was explicitly defining build hint `android.playService.plus` instead of using `android.includeGPlayServices=true`  (cf. https://www.codenameone.com/blog/a-thank-you-an-important-update-on-android-builds.html)

PS: The information on the Google+ login blog (http://www.codenameone.com/google-login.html) needs to be updated.